# iPhone Simulator: start iPad by default?

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

Can I somehow force a specific hardware device when running my universal app? Whenever I rebuild and test, iPhone 3 fires up and I have to switch over to iPad and rotate the device.
Annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Project > Edit Project Settings > Targeted Device Family > iPad

Comment: But in a universal app, if this is "iPad only", it will load the incorrect MainWindow.xib, namely the one of the iPhone. I have to adjust that too, everytime I want to test.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this problem myself.

First, install new version of xCode, which is xCode 4.

Then set project scheme to iphone simulator and run app in xCode several times.

And re-install xCode 3 and the problem will be gone away!